# shmat() returning error when used in child process

Tags: c

I am trying to use IPC shared memory in a child process,this shared memory is created in its parent process with same key values as is used in the child process.
The parent process stores some values in the shared memory and i want to access those values in the child process.

I wrote the following code for the child process:

```
if ((p_id = fork()) < 0) 
{
    perror("fork");
    return 1;
}
if(p_id == 0)
{
    int element=-1;
    int *front;
    int *queue[100];
    int *rear;
    key1=5678;
    int queue_index=0,ii;
    for(queue_index=0;queue_index<count_machine_type;queue_index++)
    {
        if((queue_c[queue_index] = (int *)shmat(shmid[queue_index],0,0))==(int *)-1)
            printf("error in shmat queue\n");
        key1+=1;
    }
    if(( front_c = (int *)shmat(shmid_front,0,0))==(int *)-1)
        printf("error in shmat front\n");
    if(( rear_c = (int *)shmat(shmid_rear,0,0))==(int *)-1)
        printf("error in shmat rear\n");
}
```

The child process is unable to access the shared memory.
it returns `-1` every time.

Comment: When a system call returns with a error, then you should check what error it was. Do it by using e.g. [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to print a nice descriptive string about the error. Or print it using [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) and passing [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) (which is the variable containing the actual error code).